# Mockito. Method invocation count in the internal object being created

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, mockito

I have some class and method:

```
class Verificator {

   private Dao dao;
   private VerifyConsts verifyConsts;

   @Autowired
   public Verificator(Dao dao, VerifyConstants verifyConsts) {
        this.dao = dao;
        this.verifyConsts = verifyConsts;
   }

   public List<Pair<Products, Problem>> verify(final List<Product> links) {
     //do smth
     return new ProductVerifyLink().verifyLinks(links, verifyConstants.getForisInstanceZoneId(), dao.getDate());
   }

}
```

I have another class:

```
public class ProductVerifyLink {

    public List<Pair<Products, Problem>> verifyLinks(List<Product> links,
            final ZoneId zone,
            final Timestamp date
    ) throws Exception {
        //do smth
        List<Pair<Product, Problem>> res = verification(ImmutableList.of(links), zone);
        return res.isEmpty() ? null : res;
    }

    private List<Pair<Product, Problem>> verification(List<Product> links, ZoneId zone) {
      //do smth
    }
    //other methods
}
```

I created test:

```
    @Test
    public void calcTest() throws Exception {   
        final DAO dao = mock(DAO.class);
        final VerifyConstants verifyConsts = mock(VerifyConstants.class);
        final Verificator verifyLinks = Mockito.spy(new Verificator(dao, verifyConsts));

        final List<Product> links = ImmutableList.of(
                createUmrsLink(true, 2042229422, dateTime));
        final List<Long> linkIds = links.stream().map(Product::getProductId).collect(Collectors.toList());

        final List<Pair<ProductUmrs, VerifyProblem>> pairs = verifyLinks.verify(links);
    }
```

I want to check that method `ProductVerifyLink.verification` called once and with the arguments necessary to me. How can use `Mockito` and `JUnit` make it?

The whole problem is that the object of this class (`ProductVerifyLink`) is created inside, and outside I can not influence it.

Comment: I can't see `ProductVerifyLink.verification`metod on the class `ProductVerifyLink`with provided code in the question. Can you provide the correct source code?

Comment: I updated my question. In class `ProductVerifyLink` have method `verification`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't verify private methods with mockito, hence you can do it with [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock)

But I can suggest you to test return of your public method, so you do also test get through your flow including private methods.